# How to select non exist data in 1 table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need some sql query help here.

I have 1 table which is dbo.invoice.

```
| PO_NO     | TYPE          | MOVEMENT_TYPE     | QUANTITY  | SALESREF  | FLOW  |
|---------- |-----------    |---------------    |---------- |---------- |------ |
| 10001001  | G.RECEIPT     | 101               | 1000.00   | 5001      | S     |
| 10001001  | G.RECEIPT     | 101               | 2000.00   | 5002      | S     |
| 10001001  | G.RECEIPT     | 122               | 1000.00   | 5001      | H     |
| 10001001  | G.RECEIPT     | 122               | 1500.00   | 5002      | H     |
| 10001001  | INVOICE       |                   | 1000.00   | 5001      | S     |
| 10001001  | INVOICE       |                   | 2000.00   | 5002      | S     |
| 10001001  | INVOICE       |                   | 1500.00   | 5002      | H     |
```

The output that I want is  to display Type = G.RECEIPT that do not have any data exist on TYPE= INVOICE with SALESREF= 5001 & FLOW = H" , it will diplays like this :-

```
| PO_NO     | TYPE          | MOVEMENT_TYPE     | QUANTITY  | SALESREF  | FLOW  |
|---------- |-----------    |---------------    |---------- |---------- |------ |
| 10001001  | G.RECEIPT     | 122               | 1000.00   | 5001      | H     |
```

How can I do it?

**UPDATED**

This is my current query

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.INVOICE
WHERE MVT_TYPE = '122' and TYPE NOT IN ( SELECT TYPE FROM DBO.PO where flow ='H' )
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You cannot have both MYSQL and SQL-SERVER; please edit to leave just the correct one.

Comment: As for your question, have you tried a query and are getting wrong results?

Comment: @Eli..I just updated my post

Comment: So basically if INVOICE has no entry, return G.RECEIPT instead?

Comment: Well... you're probably getting 0 rows returned. Since all records in your example showing `TYPE` = INVOICE don't have anything for `MOVEMENT_TYPE`

Comment: can't understand "The output that I want is if TYPE = INVOICE does not exist yet for SALESREF= 5001 & FLOW = H"

Comment: @NicoVanBelle yes nico.

Comment: @Ashu I mean I want the result to display Type = G.RECEIPT that do not have any data exist on TYPE= INVOICE with SALESREF= 5001 & FLOW = H"

Comment: @safwan are you sure that you are showing correct output in your question because it is not matching with what you have said in your above comment

Answer (score 2):

Use NOT EXISTS:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.INVOICE
WHERE SALESREF = 5001 AND FLOW = 'H' AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
FROM dbo.INVOICE
WHERE SALESREF = 5001 AND FLOW = 'H' AND TYPE = 'INVOICE')
```

for all SALESREFs:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.INVOICE i
WHERE FLOW = 'H' AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
FROM dbo.INVOICE
WHERE FLOW = 'H' AND TYPE = 'INVOICE' AND SALESREF = i.SALESREF)
```

Comment: @safwan is this the answer  you were looking for?

Comment: thank you for your answer. But what if i got another SALESREF which is more than 1 other than salesref = 5001?

Comment: @Safwan 'SELECT 1 ' just helps to return TRUE for the EXISTS clause.

Comment: @Safwan I have updated my answer to hopefully answer your question.

Comment: @cloudsafe I got 1 question, why salesref = 5001 still need to put inside the query?

Comment: @Safwan As I understand it: you want to return the row where SALESREF = 5001 AND FLOW = 'H', but not if there exists a row that has SALESREF = 5001 AND FLOW = 'H' and TYPE equal to 'INVOICE'? If you want to only show the row if there does not exists any TYPE = 'INVOICE', only include TYPE = 'INVOICE' in the sub query WHERE CLAUSE.

Comment: @cloudsafe it right what you said about what you understand. SALESREF=5001 is just one example record that i wanted to test out the result before I input more data. There will be a lot more SALESREF that do not exist in TYPE= "INVOICE' & FLOW = 'H'. If I remove the SALESREF , the result will be display all with FLOW= 'H'.

Comment: @Safwan I have updated the answer again, for all SALESREFs.

Comment: @cloudsafe thank you for your support. But it wont filter TYPE = GR , SALESREF = 5002 , FLOW = H. It display all with FLOW = H. How can I filter IF TYPE = G.RECEIPT , SALESREF = 5001 (or other salesref), FLOW = H does not have TYPE = INVOICE, SALESREF = 5001 (or other salesref), FLOW = H , it will just display that TYPE GR only. Im sorry if asking too much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Correlated NOT EXISTS:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.INVOICE i
WHERE type='G.RECEIPT'
AND NOT EXISTS(
 SELECT * FROM dbo.INVOICE i2
 WHERE type='INVOICE'
 AND i.PO_NO=i2.PO_NO
 AND i.QUANTITY=i2.QUANTITY
 AND i.SALESREF=i2.SALESREF
 AND i.FLOW=i2.FLOW
)
```

This handles the requirement more generically, so that it gets all G.RECEIPT that don't have a matching INVOICE, without hardcoding values for SALESREF or any other column.